# Can a map $\mathbb{A}^{m}_{k}\rightarrow\mathbb{A}^{n}_{k}$ always be extended to projective space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, affine-varieties

Can a regular map $\phi:\mathbb{A}^{m}_{k}\rightarrow\mathbb{A}^{n}_{k}$ always be extended to $\mathbb{P}^{m}_{k}\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^{n}_{k}$?

In particular, I am interested in the map
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \phi: & \mathbb{A}^{7}_{k} & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{A}^{4}_{k}\\
          & [x_{1},...,x_{7}]  & \longmapsto     & [x_{1},...,x_{4}]
\end{eqnarray*}

I want to know whether or not that map is ***closed***. If I could extend it to a map $\tilde{\phi}:\mathbb{P}^{7}\longmapsto\mathbb{P}^{4}$, this would indeed be so: Any closed subvariety $V$ of $\mathbb{A}^{7}$ is of the form $\tilde{V}\cap\mathbb{A}^{7}$ for some projective variety $\tilde{V}\subseteq\mathbb{P}^{7}$. The variety $\tilde{V}$ is projective, hence proper, so its image $\tilde{\phi}(\tilde{V})$ in $\mathbb{P}^{4}$ would be closed. Therefore $\phi(V)=\tilde{\phi}(\tilde{V})\cap\mathbb{A}^{4}$ would be closed as well. Or is there a mistake in this argument?

Comment: What does ''lifted'' mean here? It sounds like you are fixing a particular embedding $\mathbb{A}^{n}_{k} \to \mathbb{P}^{n}_{k}$, but there are many such maps. Which one do you mean?

Comment: I found a mistake in the argument: $\phi(V)$ is in general not the same as $\tilde{\phi}(\tilde{V})\cap\mathbb{A}^{4}$. A point in $\tilde{\phi}(\tilde{V})\cap\mathbb{A}^{4}$ may be hit by an element of $\mathbb{P}^{7}$ that does not lie in $\mathbb{A}^{7}$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim I am thinking of the embedding $[x_{1},...,x_{m}]\mapsto(1:\frac{x_{1}}{x_{0}}:...:\frac{x_{m}}{x_{0}})$ which identifies $\mathbb{A}^{m}$ with the open set $U_{0}:=\mathbb{P}^{m}\setminus V(x_{0})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only maps $\Bbb P^m\to \Bbb P^n$ with $m>n$ are the constant maps. See for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3156070/constant-morphism-between-projective-varieties). As what you've written is not a constant map, it's not a map at all - for instance, the point $[0:\cdots:0:1]$ doesn't have an image under your "map".

There are easier ways to show your map $\Bbb A^7\to \Bbb A^4$ isn't closed. Consider the variety $V(x_1x_7-1)$: this is closed in $\Bbb A^7$, but it's image under the projection to  $\Bbb A^4$ is $D(x_1)$, which is not closed.

Comment: Why is that not closed?

Comment: If it were, then $D(x_1)\cup V(x_1)$ would be a decomposition of $\Bbb A^4$ as two proper closed subsets. But $\Bbb A^n$ is irreducible, so this cannot happen. Alternatively, you can show it's not equal to it's closure ($\Bbb A^4$).